# Is there a general file specification for OpenApi?

Tags: json, serialization, yaml, deserialization, openapi

I've noticed that this form of specification where you can use `$ref`'s to other declared objects is a bit of a pattern that could be used for many use cases.

Is there a name for this? Are there libraries for it?

I can see this being very useful for cases where you have relational data that you would like to be able to serialize to a JSON / YAML file and also deserialize it into objects in memory.

Here's an example of what I'm after:

I'd like to serialize this class which has references to other objects.

```cs
class Node {
   Node next;
   Node prev;
}
```

It could be serialized like:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "0": {
            "next": {
                "$ref": "#/nodes/1"
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "prev": {
                "$ref": "#/nodes/0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or maybe

```
{
    "next": {
        "prev": {
            "$ref": "#" // The root
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially it's a way to serialize Graph-like data with a Tree structure that I'm after.

Comment: `$ref` is a [JSON Reference](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03). And here's the full OpenAPI Specification: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not quite. My question is whether there are libraries built to take advantage of this `$ref` identifier so that when you deserialize the JSON only one object is created in memory - but it will be referenced by each of the other objects which referenced it using the `$ref` signature. 

And vice versa, the library will also allow you to take any Object in memory and serialize it to JSON. It will substitute references to other objects with `$ref` if those objects are referenced in multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like some Json serializers actually do support this and it isn't a separate specification - it's a feature built into the JSON spec..

See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm .